# Unable to download backup file created using All in One WP Migration WordPress plugin

Tags: plugins, migration, backup

I have installed **All in One WP Migration** WordPress plugin and activated it.

I have created backup using export as file option. Export has been done successfully, but when I am trying to download the exported file by clicking on download file, it saying download failed.

so what I understood is When I export as file, it create your-site.wpress file into   the path https://your-domain-name/wp-content/backup-file-name.wpress
but when I trying to download this file due to large size of file, it is unable to download from HTTP or my hosting is unable to download such a large file, so download is getting failed,

Please give your suggestion how can I download the exported back-up file from my hosting location that is wp-content folder ? yes I know you will say from Cpanel or FTP, download it from wp-content folder, but at the moment I don't  have access for Cpanel and FTP, any alternative solution ?

Comment: Can you connect via SSH or contact the host? Sometimes even trying a different internet connection with higher speed can affect whether or not you can download a large file through a browser.

Comment: Can you try to install the WP File Manager plugin and gain access to the file system from within the WP admin?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem too.
All my donwloads are cut at 512mb.

The problem is probably (but not sure) linked to :

• Cloudflare CDN and or Cloudflare routes (cloudflare VPN).

• Litespeed server configuration

But I can't bypass the cloudflare cache using htacess. Or using a file downloader like wp file manager too. Don't work.

Possible solution (to dev) :
Maybe having using a wordpress plugin cutting the big .wpress file into smaller of less than 512mb… let's say 500mb… using rar or something like that… can be a solution for us.